# PHP Graphical Library with Docker in Ubuntu

Tags: php, docker, ubuntu, captcha

I have Docker with php and mysqli, and I'm trying to put the graphical library in my Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

These are the lines in my PHP.Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:fpm

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libonig-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd \
    && docker-php-ext-enable gd

RUN pecl install xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
```

When i run `Docker-Compose up` and open the php file with the captcha it shows me [that fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVXrD.png). The refered lines are the ones of the captcha.

All my partners use Linux Mint, and it works in their machines, so i dont know why it doesnt work in my Ubuntu

Does someone know what am I doing wrong? I dont know what to do to run the graphical librarys (for captchas, graphics...) with docker

***SOLVED:***

I changed the old PHP.Dockerfile file and now it works!!
The problem was the version PHP in Ubuntu.
First I deleted all the *.pem from mysqldata, and then I used this lines in the PHP.Docker

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libpng-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

RUN pecl install xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
```

Then I executed *docker-compose build*. And all is good now

Comment: In your machine, the warnings are displayed. So the source of the image is not correct. Fix your PHP warnings. Your PNG image will have a correct content after that.

Comment: The php errors are because it can not read the image.ttf I think. The lines of my the php are all right.

Comment: Checkout the line 57 of captcha.php, and fix the "implicit conversion from float".

Comment: See also : https://php.watch/versions/8.1/deprecate-implicit-conversion-incompatible-float-string

Comment: What I mean is that the exactly same code works with Linux Mint, but it does not in Ubuntu, that is what i dont understand. I think the problem is in the Docker...

Comment: The difference between hosts is how PHP display warnings. The correct fix is not to hide warnings, but fix them.

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message you are facing, the code that causes that error, and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: I just posted the lines of the PHP, I also have 2 more codes, 1 is the html code (very easy form) and another php with the verification of the captcha (very simple too). Then I have the font file and the image of the captcha file.

Comment: "These are the fails of the program." - what does that mean? What **exactly** is not working?

Comment: In the image I posted you can see what is not working. Im not gonna lie, I dont understand them... The fisrt one is the "Implicit conversion from float 163.75 to int loses precision", and the second one is the modification of the header information (I think this one does not work because of the first error)

Comment: As I said before, I think the problem is the docker, becase I dont see any errors in the PHP. Im studying computing, and all my partners use Linux Mint  (I use Ubuntu) with the exact same code and it works...

Comment: "I posted you can see what is not working" - please share all error messages in text form, along with your attempts to resolve them

Comment: Also, simply by reading the error mesage, it's obvious how to resolve this: `imagettftext` asks for an integer as the fourth parameter, you use a float. That makes no sense. Also, the next error message about "headers already sent" is also an obvious one: the wrong usage of `imagettftext` prints a deprecation notice (according to your level of error reporting), and sending a header after having done **any** other output is not allowed

Comment: Thank you so much guys, I just found the error. In Ubuntu (20.04.3), with the last version of PHP (8.1.12) the graphical librarys doesnt work. So in the PHP.Dokcerfile I used and older version of PHP  (7.4). Now everything works!!